# minikube - Container image "k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy:v1.22.3" already present on machine

Tags: minikube

I deleted the minikube cluster by minikube delete and then remove the .minikube folder. When I start minikube cluster I can see event message like:

```
22m         Normal    Scheduled           pod/kube-proxy-b2lqg                            Successfully assigned kube-system/kube-proxy-b2lqg to minikube-m02
22m         Normal    Pulled              pod/kube-proxy-b2lqg                            Container image "k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy:v1.22.3" already present on machine
22m         Normal    Created             pod/kube-proxy-b2lqg                            Created container kube-proxy
22m         Normal    Started             pod/kube-proxy-b2lqg                            Started container kube-proxy
22m         Normal    SuccessfulCreate    daemonset/kube-proxy                            Created pod: kube-proxy-48qfw
22m         Normal    SuccessfulCreate    daemonset/kube-proxy                            Created pod: kube-proxy-b2lqg
```

My question is where is the container image kept? I already deleted the  .minikube folder. I checked on my host machine and there is no such image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be able to view the contents of the image under /var/lib/docker/ directory. However, the contents of the /var/lib/docker/ docker directory may vary depending on driver docker for storage.

By default this will be aufs but it can be back to overlay, overlay 2 devicemapper or zfs depending on your keneal support.
In most of the cases this will be aufs.
You can manually set the storage driver location with -s or –storage-driver option to the Docker [Daemon](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/)

/var/lib/docker/{driver-name} will contain the driver specific storage for contents of the images.
/var/lib/docker/graph/ now only contains metadata about the image, in the json and layersize files

In case of aufs:

/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/ has the file contents of the images.
/var/lib/docker/repositories-aufs is a JSONfile containing local image information. This can be viewed with command docker images.

In case of devicemapper:

/var/lib/docker/devicemapper.devicemapper/data stores the images
/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/metadata the metadata
Please note that these files are thin provided “sparse” files so they are ot as big as they seem.

For MacOS:

Docker does not run natively on a Mac because the macOS kernel isn’t compatible (i.e., BSD vs Linux). Docker is actually running in a virtual machine using HyperKit. The Docker vm disc image defaults to being in either:

$HOME/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/Docker.qcow2

OR

$HOME/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/Docker.raw

Depending on if you chose the raw filesystem or not. So the folder location of /var/lib/docker is inside of this virtual machine and not on your macOS file system which is why you can’t find it with ls

And the bottom line is that, exact location of Docker images on MacOSX has changed over a period of  time. Please check in the respective system accordingly.

Comment: But why after I deleted the .minikube folder on my host MacOS and did a minikube start, it says the images already exist on the machine? If I deleted the .minikube folder, I thought the previous downloaded images are all deleted. And on my Mac, there is no /var/lib/docker folder. If I minikube ssh into the minikube VM, I see /var/lib/docker folder.

Comment: Can you provide us the screenshot of the error, so that we can check further on this issue.

Comment: I have updated answer for MacOS please check and upvote if it helps